# HTML/JS: Scroll to Top Visual Artifact

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://daniel.concept9.ca/ - As you can see, pretty basic site - problem is that everytime I scroll down (i'm lower than the top) then hit "About" in the menu, it brings me up and opens the section **only** after displaying a full-page visual artifact for 1-2 seconds.

I'm thinking that it might have something to do with an error I'm getting in the console as soon as I load the page: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefinedglobal.min.js:42 (anonymous function)" ...but I'm on a n00b in JS...

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!
dan.

Comment: It looks like you've already change the site and have a different error. Maybe you should just keep on debugging it and post only an issue only if there is something that really stops you.

Comment: i didn't change the site... still have the same error...

Answer (score 0):

When "About" is clicked, the site:

1. Scrolls to the top
2. Switches the header position from "fixed" to "absolute"
3. Does a 3D translate on the "About" section
4. Moves the header

and as far as I can tell it attempts to do all of this simultaneously. There are some computationally intense functions there that essentially involves trying to re-render the entire page while does a javascript scroll.

In addition, there are about 25 javascript files (mostly jQuery plugins) included on the bottom of the page, most of which probably slow down the page to some degree. This is the danger is buying a nice-looking commercial theme - jQuery plugins make the page look awesome with little development work by the theme creator, but page performance suffers.

There are many ways to improve the performance of this action and get rid of the rendering artifacts, but likely nothing quick and easy. The easiest way would probably be to make sure the scroll happens first and shows the "About" pane in a callback function. Unfortunately, most of the JS is obscured/minified so it's hard to explain exactly what to do.

Comment: hi Khan - appreciate the input! fortunately, speed isn't a huge issue - will be able to eliminate some of the JS files since I'm not using all the functions and current speed is 3s (before optimizing images). Any way I could de-minify the JS?:)

Comment: @Dan Yes, can you de-minify? I see a spot in global.js that you might be able to shim in a callback.

Comment: I tried to use a few tools to de-minify but they don't work as exprected... However, I did seem to find that when I place the files in the main folder of my domain - daniel.concept9.ca, I still get the problem. However, when I put the files in a subfolder daniel.concept9.ca/SITE/ , then the animation bug is eliminated (and console error with 'top' undefinied dissapears. Any idea what this might happen? I'm thinking it has to do with the path somehow...